# training branched-olive sapling

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, olive

I need help finding the pruning and training techniques to have branched-olive (no central axis) produced from semi-hard cuttings instead of standard format. thanks

Comment: Do you have any pictures of what your trees look like now and what you want them to look like?